# Finding Skyline Set

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

Let me just explain some definition before going to the problem:

Say point A is a coordinates(that could have double value), say (1.2,3.5,4.3,2.6),
same to point B.

A point A dominates point B, 
iff 
1. all coordinates in point A <= all coordinates in point B, and 
2. one coordinate of point A < corresponding coordinates of point B

For example:
Given

```
A=(2,3,4,5)
B=(2,3,4,6)
```

A dominates B since condition 1 holds, and for condition 2, the forth component of A < forth component of B.

Given another example,

```
A=(2,3,4,5)
B=(2,3,4,5)
```

Neither A dominates B, and vice versa, since condition 2 does not hold in both cases.

Now given a list of coordinate of n dimension, I wish to find the set of coordinates that are not dominated by others, 
these coordinates are termed as skyline set.

Say I have coordinates in 5 dimensions

```
(2,1,2,1,2)
(1,2,1,2,1)
(3,3,3,3,3)
(4,4,4,4,4)
```

The skyline set is

```
(2,1,2,1,2)
(1,2,1,2,1)
```

Now I wish to write a function:

```
List<double[]> SkylineSet(List<double[]> Coordinates, int dimension)
```

Given example input:

```
 List<double[]> newList=new List<double[]>();
 newList.Add(new double[] {2, 1, 2, 1, 2});
 newList.Add(new double[] { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 });
 newList.Add(new double[] { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 });
 newList.Add(new double[] { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 });
```

`SkylineSet(newList,5)` will output

```
(2,1,2,1,2)
(1,2,1,2,1)
```

This could be achieved by pairwise comparison of each coordinates, but the 
number of coordinates can be very large, any one has idea how to solve this efficiently?

Comment: Nope, it is not a homework, it is a practical problem I face...

Comment: No idea what's going on here. Based on the fact that entire papers and studies have been conducted to optimize the calculation, I'm afraid the scope of this problem will be too great, even for [so] to dive into. Here may be a resource of interest: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5474124

Comment: @william007 in which case, +1 for a well asked question

Comment: Update: The above IEEE paper covers algorithms only for 2D and 3D skyline calculations. It doesn't even consider the possibility of five dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the points in a K-D tree (or some such data structure). Now, You can efficiently find points dominated by a given point. Remove those that got dominated, repeat for all remaining points.

Comment: Thanks but how to do it with K-D tree? "You can efficiently find points dominated by a given point", why is it so?

Comment: Points donminated by a given point are points with all coordinates greater or equal than the coordinates of the given point. The dominated points are points inside a d-cube with one corner at the given point, the other corner being at infinity. A KD-tree allows You to find points inside a given cube efficiently. I think...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work. It seems plausible in my head. It also may be that this is exactly what you are already doing.

Build a domination matrix NxN, where N is number of points. Values in matrix are "equal", "dominating", "dominated", "neither". Set all matrix cells to "equal". This matrix holds the result in the end of the algorithm.

Start with first coordinate.

I assume here that we have one array with all values of current coordinates, but also to which point they are related to.

Establish a relation of partial domination, looking only at current coordinate. Relation of domination can have one these values: "equal", "dominated", "dominating". There is no "neither".

Run through this array in double nested loop (I = 0, N-2; J = I+1, N-1). Given relation R of two points and cell C in relation matrix for these two points update the matrix to new values C like this:

If C was "equal" then C = R.
If C was "neither" then it is unchanged.
If C was "dominated" and R is "dominating" then C becomes "neither", otherwise is unchanged.
If C was "dominating" and R is "dominated" then C becomes "neither", otherwise is unchanged.

Repeat the process for all coordinates, accumulating results in the matrix.

In the end run through the matrix for each point. Take all points that have no "dominated" relation with any other point.

Comment: this is O(N^2), You can get O(N^2) by just checking all pairs of points (the points not dominated by any other point are in the skyline set).